# Family land in Texas

Tags: united-states, taxes

My grandfather owned land in Texas, which was just sold by our family, and the proceeds were allocated to all the grandchildren.  I received a portion of the proceeds.

I'm curious how that should be handled on my taxes.

I'm not an investor, so I don't have much experience with capital gains.  However, I'm not sure this should be treated as capital gains, since it wasn't an investment for me.

Is this just treated as income?

Comment: Was it a distribution of his inheritance, or a sale after the inheritance was already assigned to someone and then sold?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it would be either an inheritance, or a gift, depending on the details. Both have large limits before taxation starts, so if it is not millions, you are good.
If it is *big*, the estate or the gift giver would have to pay estate / gift tax.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The amount is under $10,000.  So, no, not big. If it is an inheritance or gift that is under the taxation limit, I'm assuming I would not need to declare this on taxes? Any clarity on that?

Comment: Correct. Just enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

If you grandfather was alive when the land was sold and the funds distributed:

- The grandfather has to address any gains from the sale of the land on their tax form.
- If each gift is under the annual limit, the grandfather doesn't have to even address the gifts on their tax forms. If it is over the limit they either will have to pay gift taxes or count it against their lifetime limit.
- The person who receives the money faces no tax impact. It doesn't appear on any tax form. Of course if the person who receives the gift is trying to buy a house, get financial aid for college, or certain other government programs it might have to be declared.

If the sale of the land was done as part of their estate because they recently died, then the gift rules do not apply.

- The estate will handle any taxes related to the sale of the land.
- The remain funds are then distributed according the estate plan.
- The people who receive the funds do not face any tax issues. Though again there can be non-tax forms related to financial aide, mortgages, and other government programs that may require it to be declared or explained.

It gets much more complex if the land is gifted to the grand kids and then sold. The taxes will be addressed on the recipients tax forms. There could be capital gains because the calculation will be based on the initial value of the land. It can also depend on if the property was land or if it included a house, or if it was used to generate income.

> I'm not an investor, so I don't have much experience with capital
> gains. However, I'm not sure this should be treated as capital gains,
> since it wasn't an investment for me.
>
> Is this just treated as income?

In the first two situations it isn't capital gains or income for the grandchildren. It doesn't appear on their fax forms. Now once the money is deposited or invested by the recipients it can start generating interest, dividends or capital gains which will appear on their tax forms.